# Get programmatic set EditText value

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

## Edit 4: I did my own numberpicker, so I don't need help with this anymore.

### But I think the problem is that I didn't use dialog.findViewById()...

I'm trying to get a `EditText` value, that is created programmatic. But it don't work, when the `onClick` function run the code breaks.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        numberValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_picker_value);
        Log.d("****2**", numberValue.getText().toString());

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
 });
```

The value and ID is set from another class, `NumberPicker.java`.

```
private void initValueEditText( Context context )
{
    value = new Integer( 0 );

    valueText = new EditText( context );
    valueText.setId(R.id.number_picker_value); //ID set here
    valueText.setTextSize(25);
    ...
    //value set sooner, look in the link for full code.
}
```

Full source code of NumberPicker.java can be found here [here](http://pastebin.com/dLRem5Jw).

The `R.id.number_picker_value` is defined in an XML file with
`<item type="id" name="number_picker_value" />`.

**EDIT:**

What I mean with *"the code breaks"* is that i get a `Force close dialog`.

**EDIT2:**

[Logcat output.](http://gyazo.com/f0d4a32eb2f0652c3fc9cc9b4cfa2617.png) (Is it this you want?)

**EDIT3:**

Btw, I never call on NumberPicker.java. It start itself when I load the XML file with this bit of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android           = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width    = "wrap_content"    
    android:layout_height   = "wrap_content">

    <!-- This seem to start NumberPicker.java, so I have no object to refer to. -->
    <com.android.GissaSiffran.NumberPicker
        android:id            = "@+id/numberPickerDialog"
        android:orientation   = "horizontal"
        android:layout_width  = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
        android:gravity       = "center">
    </com.android.GissaSiffran.NumberPicker>

        <!--  Canel / ok button -->
    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/cnfrm"
        android:layout_width  = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:textSize      = "13dp"
        android:textStyle     = "italic"
        android:text          = "@string/cnfrmBtn"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe I do some wrong here?

When I run `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pick_a_number_dialog); dialog.show();` the XML loads and the number picker is in the dialog and i can choose number.
But I have never started the `NumberPicker.java` with ie `NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(getApplicationContext(), null));` maybe I do wrong here? (I'm new to java).

*Btw my first post here. :)*

Comment: What do you mean by "the code breaks"? What is the error message? Are you getting a stack trace? (If so, please add it to your question.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. :) What exactly do you mean when you say *"The code breaks"*? Does the app crash with a "Force close" dialog? In this case, please post the stacktrace from your logcat. Thanks.

Comment: @alextsc thanks :) I think this is the stack tree [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c8t0N.png)

Comment: There is a logcat in eclipse. If you are windows. You can find logcat in Window->Showview->Logcat. There will be error lines. Thats what you need to post as the stacktrace.

Comment: @blessenm I just founded the Android logcat and the eclipse console, hope someone is right.

Comment: How are you specifying R.id.number_picker_value. That is supposed to be dyanmically generated. Normally I use something like setId(515); Btw I think your findViewById is returning a null object. Its not able to find the edittext in what you specified in setContentView method.

Comment: Well, you are getting a nullpointerexception at line 81 in your code likely due to something not being instantiated properly. What is your line 81 of code?
I'm getting that info from your logcat that you linked to, btw.
And, why don't you just reference the EditText you already created called `valueText`?

Comment: @jakar Line 81: `Log.d("****2**", numberValue.getText().toString());` I can't. I don't know why, but the _NumberPicker.java start itself_ when i load the XML that contains `<com.android.GissaSiffran.NumberPicker>`. I never call on NumberPicker, but it still popup in the dialog and log messages to the logcat when I press + or -. So... ...I have no object(?) to refer to, if you meant something like `numberPicker.valuetText;`

Answer (score 0):

For future referencers, I'm using the same NumberPicker.java I would guess.  In order to get the value of the EditText, I created a reference to the EditText in the OnCreateView method like this:

```
private EditText txtQty;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_numberpicker,container,false);

    txtQty = (EditText) view.findViewById(idText);

    return view;
}
```

Then in the onClick method:

```
String newOnHand = txtQty.getText().toString();
```